# how to fetch all order items through loop from json data api ? magento2

Tags: magento2, json, array

Hi i have an array coming from json data of placed order items in my api in this form.  let's suppose this example :

```
[items] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                 [item_id] => 392
                 [name] => ketchup 20g
                 [qty] => 2
                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (

                    [item_id] => 393
                    [name] => Powder 
                    [qty] => 1
                )

        )
```

-------------php code for dumping array data on screen -------

```
 $result=  json_decode($result);
 echo "<pre>";
 print_r($result);
 echo "</pre>";
```

...........
Basically i wants to fetch all order items placed by customer in one order.

```
echo $result->items[0]->name;
```

this code is returning one item name at a time manually ,but let's suppose if one order has multiple items , how can i fetch it through loop? please guide

Answer (score 1):

in my case due to array data are coming in multiple indexes so this worked for me: i hope it may help anybody

```
foreach ($result2 as  $value) {

      foreach($value as  $value2)
       {

        foreach($value2 as $value3)
           {
            foreach($value3->items as $value4)
               {
                    print_r($value4->name);
                    echo '<br>';
               }
           }
       }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a standard way to do it.

```
$jsondata = '';
$arr = (array)json_decode($jsondata, true);
 foreach ($arr as $k=>$v){
    echo $v; }
```